# Regex remove new line and backslashes

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a request payload that I need comes with new lines '\n' that I'm removing using the regex below:

```
replaceAll("\n", "")
```

However it then leaves such a string:

```
eK7jVPstMFlOJ\/\/PtFIOKgSODxmjpQNgm9ASwQzP0v2RJbZzVXEB5ZOKVxiILhSCng25D87K8P9oHFScbS6OsmGDIf1HMDlXmcSn0JuBFfhx36GGoLpMq3\/xH3wB1Ku5x5\/6WSiijsYit28Rf\/3ZsK2U1PCc9NVVAeoZvLsn\/skjishzVGKJv9elOgkXcoM2F3LbMlrwjw9j4lx07RbeGfq9H7+oANeLCreSZEpe7iC8+zKatT4TCrb7Q3ZW\/FlE1\/JwnOphvdcKDoQvzPrxizN9idrwidF6\/y30CkCB+aW39Bb5dB+YdXmW9eZJNt4ZlI9embs+ZwAKNgZq\/52W\/Q=="
```

hence I get the error response:**No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: (String)\"\"; line: 1, column: 0]**

How can I remove the new lines and the backslashes, only the forward slashes are to be retained

(The sample/final formatted code should look something like,with forward slashes only)

```
qRqWnruUJGoEGuBPcRRe4Td/BkesYk0KdoaNO6j7QQULZExKE8jVnFdzjJxNA2GPkazen/hcKx3+DMQ7RWupau473z6uF0iVjxcl/U6mTQbtY5tb8c/Qq64C5nYU+iplW+/e1lWyKzZed7IegNRVSABKbyyTrqTmQCghPMCY3evo/YwF0EovKw5Zw1U1BzjMizr7jhBihTsq71WE4MXW4iyhxGbnvPuzqpXBowjcOAyx433PjRDZnty5mum3TeETJMpoF20ULa7q5mnNCW6JbkZErhzGbY5thJNeYUvwhlsP3qFYNlFkO0kKax/nEfxFC6muowOOrFsqerbP0lcAHQ==
```

Comment: Can you include a sample payload and what end result are you after?

Comment: Remove backslashes with `.replace("\\", "")`, you do not even need a regex.

Comment: @npinti I've added the sample payload

Comment: @Wiktor,with 2 slashes this results in a crash, unless with four but it still leaves the string with something like -> `\/`

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like all you need to do is replace your backslashes too...

You can chain calls, so try something like this:

```
final String result = original.replaceAll("\n", "")
                              .replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Or, for a single line solution:

```
final String result = original.replaceAll("([\\\\\n])", "");
```

Comment: With the first solution, I am still getting something like this `\/` and with the second solution, all the back slashes and forward slashes are replaced

Comment: @Boron No, that code can't remove forward slashes. You are doing something wrong.